# is WebDav necessary for Interdev?

Tags: security, webdav, windows-server-2000

We've got a Windows 2000 server with WebDAV enabled and are told it's insecure so we should remove it. However, we've got several developer using Interdev and Interdev-enabled sites, so we're concerned they won't be able to work anymore.

Are there alternatives that will allow them to use Interdev securely, or must we disable WebDav and make the sites FTP-only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while but I believe that the WebDav ( or Front Page Server Extentions as I remember them) were only used for deployment. Back when we used Interdev we would usually develop locally with Interdev and deploy via FTPS, so I don't believe you should run into your applications if you aren't explicitly using WebDAV for anything.

Comment: I believe it will use either of two protocols: WebDAV or WEC (FrontPage Web Extender Client).  I believe InterDev 6.0 at least always auto-negotiates the protocol with the server.